# EntityFramework - Port WithRequired to EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm porting an application from MVC5/EF6 to MVC6/EF7, but having an issue with this particular line:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasMany(c => c.Payments).WithRequired(e => e.Client).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Apparently the WillCascadeOnDelete is transformed to the OnDelete with restrict as parameter, but I can't find any documentation on the "WithRequired" part which has disappeared too in EF7. Has 'WithOne' the same impact or am I completely wrong here :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasMany(c => c.Payments).WithOne(e => e.Client).OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Answer (score 6):

You are correct in both cases. Here is a detailed post... http://www.mikee.se/posts/migrating_from_ef6_to_ef_core

> Typically these mappings would change from this in EF6.

```
x.Entity<Company>()
    .HasMany(c => c.StatementOfEarnings)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Company)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

> To this in EF Core

```
x.Entity<Company>()
    .HasMany(c => c.StatementOfEarnings)
    .WithOne(e => e.Company)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```